# How to take the last vowel and any words after it of a string in Scala?

Tags: java, string, scala, dictionary

Given the following Map("DIAMOND" -> "DAYMAHND", "THOUSAND" -> "THAWZAHND"), I want to take the value of each item in the current map and update those values in a new map with the last vowel and every other word after it as values and the same word as keys. How would I do this in Scala? I heard of people accomplishing this by using .stripSuffix(). (Maps are immutable)

Input: Map("DIAMOND" -> "DAYMAHND", "THOUSAND" -> "THAWZAHND")

Output: Map("DIAMOND" -> "AHND", "THOUSAND" -> "AHND")

My Attempt:

```
val table1 = Map("DIAMOND" -> "DAYMAHND", "THOUSAND" -> "THAWZAHND")
val table2 = table1.map { case (key, value) =>
                            val string_2 = value
                                        .reverse
                                        .takeWhile("AEIOU".indexOf(_) == 
                                 -1)
                                (key, string_2 + value.charAt(value.length 
                                - 1 - string_2.length))
                                 }
                                .toMap
```

Comment: You can use `ms mapValues f `. See: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html

Comment: @FlorianBaierl Be careful with `mapValues`, it can badly affect performance if `f` is an expensive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table1.mapValues(w => w.drop(w.lastIndexWhere("AEIOU".contains(_))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is probably the best approach. This is the simplest way to do it

```
table1.mapValues(_.split("(?=[AEIUO])").last)
```

However `mapValues` will re-compute this expression each time you read the map, so if you will use the map multiple times, do this:

```
table1.map{case (k, v) => k -> v.split("(?=[AEIUO])").last}
```